# Dock keeps "wiggling" or "bouncing"

Tags: macos, dock, high-sierra

i have very weird bug that really bothers me.

My dock keeps "wiggling" or "bouncing around". 
It looks like someone is kicking on Dock back and forth for ever. Started this morning and i have not installed any apps since then.[image: gif of the dock bouncing around]

It's really annoying and i have no idea whats going on.
What i've tried : Restarted my MBP 3 times, killed Dock multiple times and still no results.

Comment: did you add anything to dock today?

Comment: Nope I did not 

Comment: Strange problem.. i hope you find a solution.

Comment: @jmh thanks. The only thing I did is remove an icon for the Dock 

Comment: have you tried putting it back just to see if it helps.

Comment: try restarting the dock    .   killall Dock    .  in terminal

Comment: @junme already mentioned i did. No success :(

Comment: Just for giggles and grins, try resizing the dock temporarily in the System Prefs.

Comment: @bjbk Will do when i get back to work on friday. I did try resizing with the handle when you over the ` | `

Comment: Strangest thing. Almost as though it is unsuccessfully trying to resize to fill the space left by the removed icon. Hope you get it figured out. Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk I know right ? Thanks ill keep this post updated if i find a solution. I contacted Apple support and they will assist me on Friday.

Comment: It's almost as if something is launching and dying really quickly. I'd try using Activity Monitor to see if I could see anything launching and quickly disappearing. Or checking Console to see if there is anything there about something repeatedly launching.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Will try that tomorrow ! :) Makes sense.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan it was that indeed ! Thanks a lot. I will post my answer with the reason with it was happening and what was causing it. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was one of [Synergy 2 beta](https://symless.com/synergy) background service that was crashing and restarting over and over again.

Thanks to https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4007/alistair-mcmillan who pointed that in my question's comments.